# How to use Angellist API?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the Angellist API but having no luck and unfortunately their `Test Endpoint` feature fails.  Here is the code that I currently have:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const key = 'MY_API_KEY';

var options = {
    url: `https://community-angellist.p.mashape.com/jobs?access_token=${key}`,
    json: true,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "X-Mashape-Key": key,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key,
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
};

rp(options)
.then(response => {
    console.log('RESPONSE: ', response);
});
```

I am getting the error `{"message":"Invalid Mashape Key"}`

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I am replacing `MY_API_KEY` with my actual api key.  It is not clear if I am passing the key in the correct part of the request because `"X-Mashape-Key": key` in the `Headers` does not seem to work.

Can someone please tell me how to make a simple request to the Angellist API to get all jobs?

Comment: …you know you have to replace MY_API_KEY with your actual key, right?

Comment: _the documentation is very poor_ you mean this: https://market.mashape.com/community/angellist ? What is poor about that? I've rarely seen such a clear documentation. All you have to do is to recreate a curl request.

Comment: I doubt you should be using the same key for both `X-Mashape-Key` and `Authorization`.  I would expect they would be different values.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to follow the [Get Jobs documentation](https://market.mashape.com/community/angellist#get-jobs)

Comment: @georej Did you get it working?